# Mysql group by order while rows with same reference but not all

Tags: sql, mysql

i have simple table

| id | order_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 2 |
| 2 | 42 | 2 |
| 3 | 45 | 3 |
| 4 | 46 | 3 |
| 5 | 47 | 2 |

i want to group order_ids by user_id order. so i will have result like this

1. 34,42
2. 45,46
3. 47

so make group order_ids while user_ids are same. then start grouping again

Comment: Please provide table structure and queries you have tried:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example